# How can I use iCloud mail on macOS 10.2.8?

Tags: macos, icloud, mail.app

I have an iMac G4 with macOS 10.2.8 and I want to use iCloud Mail with it. I had created the “For App Password” in my AppleID settings but when I try to add my AppleID to the mail app it says that it can’t connect to `imap.mail.me.com`! I already tried to add `Port: 993` later `imap.mail.me.com` but it gives me the same error!

How and can I resolve that problem?
I hide the mail for privacy question.
[image]

Comment: Have you checked that all yours settings are as documented on https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202304 ? Could you provide a screenshot of your settings page?

Comment: Now I upload a photo of the configuration screen

Comment: I've added a partial answer below. It may need some tweaking &/or input from others to finalise it [I hope;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to get as much info into that setup panel as possible & see if you can get past it to the next step, where it actually creates an account & inbox in the Mail app.

Apple states that Mail is only supported from OS X 10.7.5 & up.
This may be because any older OS will not support the versions of SSL or TLS needed.

I can't check back that far. Modern macOS iCloud setuip is almost seamless & there are no user-adjustable settings any more.
Going back as far as El Capitan, the settings were more visible, so I've grabbed some screenshots to see if you can match these settings yourself. The accounts are all set to inactive on this Mac, so areas are greyed out that won't be for you.

Once you've managed to get past that setup page [it *is possible* even if it won't connect, but it's been so long I cannot remember precisely how you do it], it will then let you add more information manually. First open Mail preferences. Select Accounts then the specific iCloud account. You should hopefully see something similar to this…

[image]

This should essentially be the same info as you set initially [ignore that the IMAP address has a 'p37' prefix for now [that comes later, if at all].

Click Outgoing Mail Server, then Edit SMTP list…

[image]

Account info & Advanced need completing…

[image]

[image]

Here you set port 587, Use SSL & either Apple Token, or if that doesn't work, Password & add a password below & OK to close it.

Click the Advanced tab back in the main panel. The important part is highlighted in red. Enter port 993, SSL & again, if Apple Token doesn't work, you *may* be able to use Password instead [I cannot test that]

[image]

If you get anywhere near being able to complete those forms & it still doesn't work it might be an SSL issue. Apple recommends switching to TLS if SSL doesn't work, but I'm almost certain OS X 10.2 will not support TLS 1.2, which is the minimum requirement for any secure TLS connection these days.

I wish you luck, if you can get this far. Add info if it feels like you're getting close but not quite there. I don't remember how those panels looked 15 or more years ago & don't have access to anything older than El Capitan to check.

Comment: imap.mail.me.com [still supports TLS v1.0](https://www.immuniweb.com/ssl/imap.mail.me.com/1NCa1nvU/), which was current when Mac OS X 10.2 was released. So that shouldn't be a problem (until they drop v1.0 support, which I'm frankly surprised they haven't already done). But imap.mail.me.com only accepts connections on port 993 (imap+SSL/TLS), not 143 (plain imap, maybe with `STARTTLS`), so if the old version of Mail is just trying 143 that might be the problem.

Comment: I just tried from Mac OS X 10.3.9, and wasn't able to get it to work. Looks like while the client & server both support TLSv1.0, they don't support any of the same cipher specs, so even after getting it all set up the mailbox remained resolutely offline (no more error messages, just... offline). (Setup was pretty much as described above; getting past the setup involved clicking "Continue" through a bunch of error/warning dialogs.) So I think a third-party mail client is the only option.