# Apple Mail - different password for incoming and outgoing servers?

Tags: mail.app, email

I have an email account that uses different password for incoming (POP3) and outgoing (SMTP) servers. How do I add such an account in Apple Mail?

It seems that Mail let me specify different server addresses but not different server passwords.

Comment: I covered this, coincidentally for completely different reasons, in a post yesterday - it shows where each password goes. See if it helps - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/438642/85275